# How to get digital persona OnEnroll events in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am moving from VB to C# with a Windows application; I am using digital persona finger print scanner to capture employee finger print which is working fine, but I am unable to get the `OnEnroll` event in C# - which I did on VB.

This is my VB code

```
Private allReaderSerial As String = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
Private WithEvents enrollControl As DPFP.Gui.Enrollment.EnrollmentControl

Private Sub CreateDPControl(ByRef control As DPFP.Gui.Enrollment.EnrollmentControl)
    Try
        control = New DPFP.Gui.Enrollment.EnrollmentControl()
        control.AutoSizeMode = Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink
        control.MaxEnrollFingerCount = 1
        control.Name = "enrollControl"
        control.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)
        control.ReaderSerialNumber = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
        control.Visible = True
        control.Enabled = True
        Me.Controls.Add(control)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("exception", MsgTitle, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub frmBioCapture_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If enrollControl Is Nothing Then
        CreateDPControl(enrollControl)
    End If
End Sub

Private WithEvents enrollControl As DPFP.Gui.Enrollment.EnrollmentControl
Private Sub enrollControl_OnEnroll(ByVal Control As Object, ByVal FingerMask As Integer, ByVal temp As DPFP.Template, ByRef EventHandlerStatus As DPFP.Gui.EventHandlerStatus) Handles enrollControl.OnEnroll
    staffTemplate = temp
    Me.Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub enrollControl_OnReaderDisconnect(Control As Object, ReaderSerialNumber As String, Finger As Integer) Handles enrollControl.OnReaderDisconnect
    MsgBox("Fingerprint reader is not conneted. Connect fingerprint reader.", vbExclamation, MsgTitle)
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

The code above is working fine am able to get the `OnEnroll` event using

```
Handles enrollControl.OnEnroll
```

I want to achieve the same task in C# - below is the code I have written so far:

```
private string allReaderSerialize = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";
private DPFP.Gui.Enrollment.EnrollmentControl enrollControl;
private DPFP.Template template;

public FrmCapture()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void CreateDPControl(DPFP.Gui.Enrollment.EnrollmentControl control)
{
    try
    {
        control = new DPFP.Gui.Enrollment.EnrollmentControl
            {
                AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink,
                MaxEnrollFingerCount = 2,
                Name = "enrollControl",
                BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.FormBackground,
                BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch,
                Location = new Point(0, 0),
                ReaderSerialNumber = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                Visible = true,
                Enabled = true
            };

        this.Controls.Add(control);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}

private void FrmCapture_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Location = new Point(400, 180);

    if (enrollControl == null)
    {
        CreateDPControl(enrollControl);
    }
}

private void EnrolControl_OnReaderDisconnected(object control, string ReaderSerialNumber, int finger)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Fingerprint reader is not connected. Connect fingerprint reader.");
    return;
}

private void EnrollControl_OnEnroll(object control, int fingerMask, DPFP.Template temp, DPFP.Gui.EventHandlerStatus eventHandlerStatus)
{
    template = temp;
}
```

With with what done capturing is working, but I can't get the the `OnEnroll` event ("Capturing completed").

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding it to `Controls` collection you can attach the handler like this.

```
 control.OnReaderDisconnect += EnrolControl_OnReaderDisconnected;
```

C# uses `+=` operator to bind a handler to an event, and `-=` to unhook it.

Comment: thanks but am not sure i got you correct, before now i tried adding the event to the designer like this ' this.enrollControl.OnEnroll += new System.EventHandler(this.EnrollControl_OnEnroll);' but i got a red underline with error message _No overload for EnrollControl_OnEnroll matches delegate eventhandler_

Comment: One thing is that you might not be binding the event like in VB through handles. Another possibility is some bug in the port so you are not receiving it.

Comment: Yeah that error is expected since your handler does not confirm to the delegate's type. Check in the docs what OnEnroll's delegate looks like.

Comment: ' public event _OnEnroll OnEnroll;'   'public delegate void _OnEnroll(object Control, int FingerMask, Template Template, ref EventHandlerStatus EventHandlerStatus);'  these are the delegate i found in **metadate**

Comment: Try doing this: `enrollControl.OnEnroll += this.EnrollControl_OnEnroll;` You cannot, and should not, treat this as an `EventHandler` since this `_OnError` does not match the event pattern employed throughout .net framework.

Comment: Hello everyone please I need suggestion to get pass this am so stock right and am out of options, please help thanks